# Does using multiple Google Maps API violate the TOS?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

I've read the official documents of Google, but I could not find about my question.

I'd like to get route data by using DirectionsService.route() in Google Maps JavaScript API(browser key, client-side), and based on them draw routes on map loaded by Google Maps Android API(Android key, server-side).

I realized this on my developing android app, but I fear I violate the TOS of Google.
Its documents don't seem to prohibit this definitely, as far as I read.
But I'm not sure whether this is possible.
Does this way violate the TOS?

Comment: Go to this for more info https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#understanding-terms-of-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the TOS that prohibits you from doing so as far as I know. As long as you render the map and supporting services using the data you requested and following the other guidelines, you should be fine.